# how to make awesomeCloud clickable

Tags: cloud, html5-canvas

kindly take a look about this word cloud i just want to make the words linkable 
so can anyone help http://indyarmy.com/awesomeCloud/

Answer (score 1):

**Drawing a Word Cloud in canvas is simple.  Making it clickable is fairly complicated!**

Canvas is a “draw and forget” tool.  After a word is drawn on the canvas it becomes just a *picture* of a word.  There is no built-in function to track where the word is on the canvas, much less click on a particular word.

If you have flexibility in your tools, you might try using a toolkit that supports clicking.  There are many possibilities, but these come to mind:

*Canvas Libraries:* Canvas drawing libraries like fabricJS, easelJS, kineticJs, paperJs (these libraries can make your canvas words clickable and trackable).  You will have to design your own clouds by moving/rotating your words.

*SVG:* Svg elements become part of the Html DOM and are therefore clickable.  RaphaelJS is a really good Svg library. You will have to design your own clouds by moving/rotating your words.

*Canned Cloud Apps:* Tagul (http://tagul.com/blog) is an app created in flash that creates clickable word clouds. By default, the links point to google searches, but you can customize each word link to point to your desired location.

If you *really* want  to “do-it-yourself” here’s how:

Download awesomeCloud from Github (https://github.com/indyarmy/jQuery.awesomeCloud.plugin)

As you draw each word, you need to keep track of it like this:

-- Use context.measureText(“your word”) to find the width of your word.

-- Create a bounding box using your word’s width and height and save that bounding box’s position and size.

-- Move and Rotate your word into position using a matrix transform and save that matrix transform.

Let the user click on your cloud.

When a user clicks on your cloud, do hit-testing against each word in your cloud.  To do this you use your saved matrix transform to un-move and un-rotate the clicked point. Then you iterate through each word’s saved bounding box and see if the clicked point is inside the bounding box.

If you get a hit, you know which word the user clicked!

Answer (score 0):

Try this fork:

https://github.com/fguimara/jQuery.awesomeCloud.plugin

You have to change something like this:

```
 <span data-weight="18">Google</span>
```

for this:

```
<span data-weight="18"><a href="http://google.com">Google</a></span>
```